# Aggregate functions in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm very new to R and trying to experiment with ggplot in particular and I'm really liking it so far.

I'm trying to plot my study hours by week, by module, but in my data I have multiple instances of study for each module (in attached image)

[image: Dataset]

I'm wanting to create a line graph where x = week commencing (W.C), and y = Hours by the cumulative total for the module.

Here's my code:

```
Study_Hours %>%
  ggplot(aes(W.C, Hours, colour = Module)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5)
```

Here's my output:

[image: Output]

So basically, I need to group the hours by module for each week commencing, but I'm not sure how to write it? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). You could just include your data directly via `dput(Study_Hours)`.

Comment: This said: You could try `stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = "sum", size = 3, alpha = 0.5)` to compute the sum of Hours per Module and W.C..